# Error in Building Java Native Interface to the OpenCV library on Android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm new to OpenCV on Android. Right now, I'm trying to configure it on my MacOSX.

I follow these instructions : http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Macintosh.pdf

When I reach this step (Build JNI to the OpenCV library) using this command:

```
sh ./project_create.sh
```

The console show this error report.

```
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android update' command.
```

How to set up the target. Does it concern with local.env.mk file. 
If it does, this is what's inside it:

```
#location of android-opencv.mk file that was generated by the cmake build
#of opencv for android
OPENCV_CONFIG=../build/android-opencv.mk

#the root directory of the crystax r4 ndk - ndk-build should be in this dir
#you can download the ndk from http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php
#ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$(HOME)/android-ndk-r4-crystax
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/Users/farissyariati/android-ndk-r4-crystax/
#define only armeabi-v7a to make the final apk smaller or armeabi
ARM_TARGETS="armeabi armeabi-v7a"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't follow the deprecated tutorial.

Comment: Still an issue with the docs at https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing

Answer (score 2):

For you Error"Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a `--target` to the '`android update`' command."

Here is the solution .In the Android-jni directory type the Following command in  Terminal

```
android update project -t 1 -p . -s
```

Here is  a list of Build targets You can use by changing the number after **`-t`**.

Available Android targets:

**id: 1 or “android-7″**

> Name: Android 2.1-update1
>
> Type: Platform
>
> API level: 7
>
> Revision: 3
>
> Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854

**id: 2 or “android-8″**

> Name: Android 2.2
>
> Type: Platform
>
> API level: 8
>
> Revision: 3
>
> Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854

**id: 3 or “android-10″**

> Name: Android 2.3.3
>
> Type: Platform
>
> API level: 10
>
> Revision: 2
>
> Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854

I was also having the same problem and it solved mine.you can also find  more build targets

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 1):

Current number of target platform depends on count of downloaded SDK. Please execute the command below to ensure that you set a correct target platform:

```
android list target
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this commands

```
->$Android list target:
id: 1 or "android-21"
     Name: Android 5.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 21
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64
```

I already set this options on the command "`android update project -t 1 -p . -s`"
until here is all good, but when I execute ./setup_env.sh I have the same problem: Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide `a --target to the 'android update`' command.

someone,please o/